# Linux boxes authenticated with expired AD password

Tags: linux

I have Linux CentOS 6&7  server, which authenticate with AD users and credential. The user's password is expired in AD server instead of that user is able to login linux boxes with a warning. I don't want user to login with expired password.[image description]

Answer (score 2):

assuming you're using sssd (you haven't said), you need to disable the credentials caching.

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/deployment_guide/sssd-cache-cred

```
[domain/EXAMPLE]
cache_credentials = true
```

and also, look into `offline_credentials_expiration` in sssd.conf

Comment: I am using only kerberos( krb5.conf) file for authentication. When I am disabling user in AD then it's not authenticating. However it authenticate with expired user password.